# Allow byte array as version column in Entity Developer

Tags: c#, nhibernate

we use Entity Developer for NHibernate with MS SQL Server. We want to let the db create the Version property with sql-type="timestamp". But the .Net Equivalent of sql-type timestamp is a byte array, which we can't select in Entity Developer for Version property. We always get the message "Version property may be of type Int64, Int32, Int16, Ticks, Timestamp, or TimeSpan"

So is it possible, and how, to get this mapping:

```
<version name="Version" type="Byte[]" generated="always">
  <column name="Version" not-null="true" sql-type="timestamp" />
</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF anyone has the same problem: I find the solution by myself. It is possible to select the data type "Binary" for Version column although the message box doesn't list this option.